# Datasets for PDF information extraction

Tags: data-request, pdf

Are there any open datasets available for PDF information extraction. The documents can be insurance claims, invoice, legal contracts, rental agreements, financial reports etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [data.gov](https://www.data.gov/) portal to search your target words, like "contracts" and then put a filter on PDF :: [example query](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=contracts&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc&res_format=PDF&as_sfid=AAAAAAVDN7LJJaREyVeQ-UoxLa0E3OjjXJ4yifKGnJ14IRq8-ZNj36_EIzRYSaDBlhWZ4MtjfSPcoR7L9YiWghoINMux6I2G5Q7yQlq9U8aKboBai-9LsUPFIFiqHRHxrh9gH_s%3D&as_fid=349e9a4b101ef32c6536e45caa077a0c21b2fdd5&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C2.4601811810210052%2C-59.0625%2C58.63121664342478)

Another option would be to use [FOIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_Information_Act_(United_States))'ed files, which may come as PDF, take a look at [Muckrock.com](https://www.muckrock.com).

Comment: can you help me with this?
https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19835/dataset-of-pdf-invoices
I have looked all over the websites that you sent me, and I could not find anything