# Dataset of PDF invoices

Tags: data-request, pdf

I'm looking for examples of PDF invoices. I want to write a code for extraction and analysis.

I need PDF invoices from companies such as Uber, Amazon, AliExpress, Nike, Adidas, Apple, Huawei, all kind of internet providers and phone network providers, hotels etc.

It would be good if examples are on english, but german is also good.

I have looked all over the Kaggle, UCI ML Repository, GitHub but I have found only 2-3 pdf invoice documents. It would be great if you can tell me where can I download more of the REAL PDF invoices

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely it's available or available for free. Invoice data is a personal data or include personal data, and I guess the only legal way to collect such a dataset is to crowdsource it.

Other sources of such data are email providers, but I don't think that any of them would easily break users' privacy.

Comment: are there any pdf invoices with dummy data, or something like that?
I do not mean totally dummy, for example "example client", 'example company' but some random generated pdf invoices

Comment: Several invoice generators generate invoices in Uber or Amazon-style, but you are looking for real-world examples, if I understand right. Real-world invoices exist only in original systems and peoples mailboxes. And it's Personally Identifiable Information (PII) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually open-licensed, but leaked documents sometimes contain large amounts of invoices.

Example: https://github.com/mttaggart/I-S00N/blob/main/0/9fd06037-11f1-4ad5-9a7d-cbfb3fa4193b.md

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/femstac/Sample-Pdf-invoices

Updated the Link to get sample Invoices